# what does a linq query return when no results are found

Tags: linq, null

i'm using a query to see if a user already exists in the database. if it finds a user, it adds it to the list (not database), and presents a message. if the user does NOT already exist, the program moves on to add the user.

the problem exists when adding the query result to a list, when the result found nothing. if the query found nothing (user does not yet exist) the returned value isn't null or 0, so i'm not sure how to check for this.

my code works fine, but my problem is trying to find a more elegant approach. i try to add the query results to a list. if it his the "catch", it means the user does not exist and it shall be added. right now my code is:

```
     var userIsNew =
                        from f in controlEntities.Users
                        where (f.UserId == userIdTextBox.Text)
                        select f;

                    List<Users> temp = new List<Users>(); 

                    try
                    {
                        temp = userIsNew.ToList<Users>();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //do nothing
                    }


                    if (temp.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This UserId already exists in the Database. \nPlease try another UserId.");
                    }
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: [Logic by exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264997.aspx) is *almost always* wrong.

Comment: Calling `.ToList<User>` on the result that returns no matches should work just fine.  It will just be a list with 0 entries in it.

Comment: that was what i first tried. but when i try to add a result with no matches to any sort of list, it throws an exception. so my workaround was to use this thrown exception as a way to execute the rest of my code.

Comment: When you call `temp = userIsNew.ToList<Users>()`, what exception is thrown when the result is empty?

Comment: the exception only says 'an error occurred while processing this request'

Comment: Ermm.. What data type is `controlEntities.Users`?  Sounds suspiciously like a type that is attempting to provide LINQ support but not very well.  If the list is pretty small and the storage backend isn't providing any added benefit (such as a Database Engine that filters the results), you could query on `controlEntities.Users.ToList()` so that the querying logic is done entirely client-side.

Comment: hmm let me try that, thank you. controlEntities.User is a wcf web data service accessing tool for the database.

Comment: Note that if you do that, you will be getting the entire list of users each time.  Like I said, I'm not sure if your web service is able to interpret `where f.UserId == ...` and return 1 result instead of the whole list.  So that may not be the best approach for network performance and scalability.  You'll want to assess that before you go with my suggested solution.

Comment: yes, your advice is sound in regards to the list size and whatnot. but that worked! i can remove the try-catch block entirely. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
        var userIsNew = (from f in controlEntities.Users
                                where (f.UserId == userIdTextBox.Text)
                                select f).FirstOrDefault();


        if (userIsNew != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This UserId already exists in the Database. \nPlease try another UserId.");
        }
```

Comment: Being null and empty are two different things so I am not convinced that this is a correct answer.  I have seen a query return a non-null object even though the query results within the object indicate nothing was found.

Comment: FirstOrDefault should return null if no results are found always surely? Can you give detail on how it didnt with 0 results

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
        bool userIsNew = controlEntities.Users.
            Count(f => f.UserId == userIdTextBox.Text) == 0;

        if (!userIsNew)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This UserId already exists in the Database. \nPlease try another UserId.");
        }
```

It's efficient because the data server returns only a number instead of a resulset.